# PHP on IIS 7.5 - Large file download blocks connection until download is complete

Tags: php, iis, download

I want to allow users to download large video files. These files are outside of the public folder because of security reasons.

I'm using a combination of fopen(), feof(), and fread() to download the file in chuncks.

The download works fine. The video is downloaded and also works just fine. The problem is during the download. Any user who's downloading the file can't continue browsing the site until the file is downloaded. The browser is trying to establish a connection, but it hangs while the file is downloading. When the download is done, the connection is immediately established. Other users can browse the site just fine during the download, so it's not like the whole server hangs or whatever.

I'm working with PHP (CakePHP) installed on an IIS server.

A snippet of code:

```
$name = "filename.mp4";
$folder = "private/folder/";

$handle = fopen($folder.$name, "rb");

if(!$handle)
{
    echo "File not found";
}
else
{
    header("Content-length:".filesize($folder.$name));
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='filename.mp4'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    session_write_close(); // this is the solution  

    while(!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fread($handle, 1*(1024*1024));
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using sessions in the download?

Comment: There's an error in your code, add a " after filename.mp4'

Comment: The quote error is only in this example. In the actual code it's correct. I've now fixed it in the snippet though.

Comment: @Pekka The download function is not dependent on any use of sessions, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The code does not seem to use sessions but still, can you verify that `session.auto_start` setting is off?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I've managed to check the setting and session.auto_start = 0. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. As suggested above, the problem was indeed related to sessions. Even though session.auto_start was off, CakePHP itself was handling sessions at the moment. So, by inserting `session_write_close()` right before the while loop, the problem was solved.